# Choosing Contours

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

When integrating functions from 0 to $\infty$ of the form $\dfrac{\ln(x)}{P(x)}$, $\dfrac{x^a}{P(x)}$ and $\dfrac{x^a\ln(x)}{P(x)}$, where $P(x)$ is a polynomial that decays sufficiently quick, my book offers two type of contours, which are discribed by the following photos. Which of these contours should I choose for each of these types of functions?

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

In both case you'll let $\rho \to 0$ and $R \to \infty$, in the limit the integral is zero on the circular portions.

In the first case you want to compute $\int_0^\infty f(x)dz$ where $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0)$, in the second you want to compute  $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$ where $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}_{+}^*$